# Difficulties in translating my equations into R

Tags: macroeconomics, solow, r

I have calculated my own Solow model with energy as an input factor. I'm already pretty sure that the equations are correct but the problem I have are the results from the loop I build for the equations - it just produces NaN.
For background P[1] influences k[1] and y[1]. Also k[1] influences y[1]. And in P[1] there is a shock modeled which will give different prices in each period but will diverge against five.

I think there is a error in the loop but I don't know where the problem is.

```
# Defining the variables
s <- 0.1
A <- 1
delta <- 0.2
Pe <- 20
gamma <- 0.25
alpha <- 0.5
k_bar <- 10
T <- 100  # Anzahl der Perioden
rho <- 0.9  # Autoregressionskoeffizient
P_bar <- 20  # Mittelwert des Preises
P_bar2 <- 5 

# Initiation for k* und y*
T <- 100
P <- numeric(T)
k <- numeric(T)
y <- numeric(T)

# Stating Values
P[1] <- P_bar
k[1] <- k_bar
y[1] <- A * k_bar^alpha * (Pe / (gamma * A * k_bar^alpha))^(gamma / (gamma - 1))

# Loop for k* und y*
for (t in 2:T) {
  P[t] <- rho * P[t - 1] + (1 - rho) * P_bar2
  k[t] <- (s * A / delta) * (P[t] / (gamma * A))^(gamma / (gamma - 1))^(1 / (1 - alpha * (1 + gamma / (gamma - 1))))
  y[t] <- A * k[t]^alpha * (P[t] / (gamma * A * k[t]^alpha))^(gamma / (gamma - 1))
}


# Results
print(y)
```

The Results form R:

[1] 1.077217      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
[11]      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
[21]      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
[31]      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
[41]      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
[51]      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
[61]      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
[71]      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
[81]      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
[91]      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN

Comment: Your expression for k[t] is causing errors, because gamma / (gamma - 1) is negative and the power of a negative number does not exist when the power is not an integer. Are you sure that there are two powers in k[t].

Comment: Hi EBger, it would be helpful if you provided us the equations you're trying to implement.